# Get rid of the search address in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, address-bar

After searching for stuff in Windows Explorer and selecting `Open in new windows` in of the items' context menu, the new windows's address bar has a dedicated search address which looks like the following:

[image]

If I go up a folder (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>) it brings me back to the search results.

How can I leave the search and continue on this windows without searching, just simple navigation?

Reproduction:

- Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open Windows Explorer
- Type a name of a folder you know that exists in the search box
- When the folder shows up in the results, double click to open it, or choose "Open in new window" from its context menu
- Click the address in the address bar, you'll see a search address pattern

How do get to the proper address instead of this funky one?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior